# mySQL trigger - What is wrong with my syntax?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-insert, triggers

I need to write a trigger where if a customerName of an incoming enquiry matches a customer name in a synonymns table then the customerID from that table is used to find the customer in the customer table.

I got a trigger to work which just searched the customer table but not the synonym table first. I was thinking something like: (It's psuedo-esque code)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Find Customer` AFTER INSERT ON `enquiry` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customersmatched (enquiryID, customerID)
    SELECT NEW.id, id, customerName, customerID FROM customer, customerSynonyms WHERE
    customerSynonyms.customerName = NEW.companyName AND customer.id = customerSynonyms.customerID
    HAVING COUNT(id)=1
END;
```

The error I recieve:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 7
```

But I'm afriad this doesn't work.

Any idea how one would go about this in mySQL? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I tried this way too - it didn't work either!

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Find_Customer AFTER INSERT ON enquiry
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT customerID FROM customerSynonyms WHERE customerName = NEW.companyName) THEN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT id FROM customer WHERE id = @customerID) THEN
                INSERT INTO customersMatched (enquiryID, customerID)
                HAVING COUNT(id)=1
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Update 2**

It turns out I was WAYYY over complicating things. The customerSynonym table had the customerID stored in a column, which was all I really needed as I could just grab all the data through php with the customerID. The final trigger which works was super simple:

```
INSERT INTO customersmatched (enquiryID, customerID)
SELECT NEW.id, customerID FROM customersynonyms WHERE
customersynonyms.customerName=NEW.companyName
HAVING COUNT(id)=1
```

Thanks for all your answers, they're always very much appreciated! :-)

Comment: `INSERT INTO <2 fields> ... SELECT <4 fields>` this does not fit together.

Comment: Can you successfully run the query inside your trigger on its own?

Comment: I've updated my question with the solution I found. It was much more simple than I anything I was initially trying to do! :-P

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Find_Customer AFTER INSERT ON enquiry FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customersmatched (enquiryID, customerID)
    SELECT NEW.id, customerID FROM customer, customerSynonyms 
        WHERE customerSynonyms.customerName = NEW.companyName 
        AND customer.id = customerSynonyms.customerID
        HAVING COUNT(id)=1
END;
```

A few things to note:

- I renamed the trigger to `Find_Customer`. I'm not 100% sure if you can have a space in the trigger name
- I removed the single quotes around Find_Customer and enquiry. The single quotes could be read as a string literal by mysql and cause problems. It's better to avoid that if possible.
- I changed your select query to only select NEW.id and customerID, since those are the only two things you're inserting. You might have to play with the select a little bit more to get it exactly how you want it.
- If this is just part of the trigger, and you have more than just a one-statement trigger, you'll need to set delimiters. Basically, you'd have `delimiter |` before the trigger definition, and then `END|` instead of `END`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed response! I'll try it out first thing tomorrow morning. I'm running it through phpMyAdmin, so I can set the delimiters to something else just for this query and it should run fine! Thanks again! I'll let you know if I run into any bumps along the way!

Comment: So I got it compile fine as a trigger, although the logic doesn't seem to be working. Is there a better, cleaner way to - If I find a customerName match in the customerSynonyms table, to then grab the customerID from that same row and then use that to lookup the customer in the customer table? My code is below: 

`INSERT INTO customersmatched (enquiryID, customerID)
    SELECT NEW.id, customerID FROM customer, customerSynonyms 
        WHERE customerSynonyms.customerName = NEW.companyName 
        AND customer.id = customerSynonyms.customerID
        HAVING COUNT(id)=1`

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using an inner join. It's clean and easy to read. I think what you'd want is something like this:
`SELECT NEW.id, customerID 
FROM customer INNER JOIN customerSynonyms ON
customer.id = customerSynonyms.customerID 
WHERE customerSynonyms.customerName = NEW.companyName
HAVING COUNT(customer.id)=1`
 If that doesn't work, try to run the regular SELECT (you'll have to replace the NEW values with something meaningful for the select) and see if you get values back, or if you get helpful output from an error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply paranoid. It turns out I was over-complicating things. Check my updated question for my solution! Thanks!